# How to find out how noisy the shutter sound of a camera is?

Tags: shutter, sound

I am looking for a (cheap, used) camera with an almost silent shutter sound that allows decent photos in low light conditions.

The main reason for this is to take pictures in churches.

How can I find out how noisy a camera is when taking pictures?

I know already that mirror-less cameras with a "big" sensor (like e.g. an APS-C sensor) are what I should be looking for.

I watched several camera reviews on YouTube, but did not find any videos where the shutter sound of e.g. the Canon EOS M10 is hearable.

Is there any other approach I could follow?

Comment: DSLR often have a low-noise shutter mode (that introduces a small delay, but for church photography this shouldn't matter). There are also sound muffling sleeves and the rather expensive "sound-blimps", but in a church the size of the latter is going to be more disturbing than the noise they aim to suppress.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik's advice is spot on: the best approach is empirical (i.e. visiting a camera store). But if you want to be more systematic, you could adopt an approach like [this one](https://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/1418138). Incidentally, that post suggests that the Fuji X100 series should be very quiet indeed (but you might be limited by the fixed lens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you state, SLR's have mirror-slap, unless you lock up the mirror. However, the *mechanical* shutter of even mirrorless cameras still makes some noise, so you might consider a camera that allows use of *only* the electronic shutter. That can have disadvantages, though, such as a 'rolling shutter" effect if the suibject is moving.

The best thing would be to visit a *camera store*, where you can look at (and listen to) various models, and get advice from the clerks.